# Assign task to account team member

Tags: custom-object, workflow, account

I have a custom object in a master detail relationship with account.

A Workflow is fired on custom object record creation.

One of this workflow action is to assign a task to the Account Team Member (the record parent)

Any leads ?

Comment: A thought: Accounts can have many Users in the Account Team. So you'll have to make assumptions which may ultimately trip you up (ie assume there's only one member in Account Team, or there's only one "Procurement Manager" in Account Team. Etc.)

Comment: Yes, there's many members on the account team indeed.

Comment: i think you need to create multiple task and assign them individually.

Comment: So you want to assign the same Task to *all* Account Team members?

Comment: RIght, I did it with trigger!!